# Child processes spawn over 16 cores but only one core do the computation

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I would like to run a function on a list of dictionaries in parallel with the help of multiprocessing.pool().

```
def foo(dictionary):
    a = dictionary['key1'] #the value of key1 is a dataframe
    b = dictionary['key2'] #the value of key2 is a dataframe
    c = a.merge(b)
    #
    #
    #...
    #other computations
    #
    #
    return final_df

all_dict = [dictionary1, dictionary2, ...] #list of dictionaries as foo's argument

len(all_dict)
16


from multiprocessing import Pool
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(16) as p:
        final = p.map(foo, [dic for dic in all_dict])


final = pd.concat(final)
```

It seems that upon the execution, the child processes have spawn but just one core start computing and some processes terminated during the execution.

[image]

The system configuration is a windows 10 server with 128 GB RAM and 32 cores.

What can be the cause?

PS: The `foo` function literally merge some dataframes which are the `"dictionary"` values and then do some computations on them and return a final dataframe. The child processes are independent from each other.

Comment: Maybe you have IO restrictions. Have you tried using imap and playing with the chunksize to see how it plays out?

Comment: multiprocessing.Pool.map works fine and your code is not runnable, therefore the issue is not reproducible. I'll concur with @FarhoodET that you might observe low CPU usage if your callback function either sleeps or is waiting on IO, but there's no real help which can be provided unless somebody has had to investigate this exact sort of issues.

Comment: @FarhoodET  Actually the len() of each "final_df which would return by "foo" is almost (900,000 , 50). So does it make these processes also "I/O" bound?

Comment: @mpy 900k is definitely not small. I'd say it's worth checking. Have you checked to see what is the size of your dataframes on disk?

Comment: @FarhoodET I guess each "final_df" with 900k records is around 300 MB and the whole "final_df" which is the concatenated one has almost 15 million records which takes 6 GB storage.

Comment: @FarhoodET Although the amount of data to read and write during each iteration is fairly huge, running one iteration (I mean if I run the program serially) takes around 10-15 minutes. So if I run the whole program serially for 16 iterations, it takes around 3 hours and almost 30 minutes. This is a lot of time for my application. So I decided to run it concurrently.

Comment: Do you load all of your data at once when you start your program? Or do you read one, process it and then close the file?

Comment: @FarhoodET all data has read at once in the program, then they sliced for iterations and finally each iteration takes its data, process them and return the final dataframe. finally all returned dataframes concatenated.

Comment: Defining `Pool(16)` will not guarantee that `16` cores are used, it only set the **max** to use. You have to set `chuncksize=` to force **one** task per core. Read up on [`map(func, iterable[, chunksize])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool%20map#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map)